# WSO2 API Authentication for multiple users

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, api-auth

I need to add multiple credentials for one API in wso2 MI. How to achieve this?

Comment: You can follow this guide - https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/rest_api_examples/securing-rest-apis/#securing-rest-apis

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow a selected set of users to access an API you may have to use role-based authorization. Where you can create a role in MI and assign this role to the users you wish to give access to, then white list this role in the API. For this, you can use this [Custom Handler](https://github.com/yasassri/wso2mi-authorization-handler/releases) and engage it like shown below.

```
<handler class="com.ycr.auth.handlers.AuthorizationHandler">
      <property name="roles" value="admin,test" />
      <property name="authorize" value="true" />
</handler>
```

You can read more on this [here](https://yasassri.github.io/posts/AuthorizationHandlerForWSO2MI/).